# Как вызвать две функции при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: php, html, функции, button

```
Есть 2 ф-ии и их нужно вызвать при нажатии на кнопку.

<input type="button" id="MsgButton" value="Отправить" onclick="addMessage()","Add()" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="button" id="MsgButton" value="Отправить" onclick="addMessage(); Add();" />
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: @Аганим Если ответ Вас устроил и проблема решена, нажмите на галочку под рейтингом ответа. Это поможет другим людям экономить свое время (не заходя в тему, которая уже решена), замотивирует участника дальше помогать, и вам будет плюсик к карме ;)